# add class to current div although other divs have the same class name in jquery

Tags: jquery

I've just started to learn jquery but i'm stuck on something i think is fairly simple.

I want to add a shadow to a div, i can do this fine but it adds a class to all the divs named menu-shadow, i only want it on the current slide.

To give you a bit more insight i have created a fiddle, you'll notice that when you go a few sub-menus up, th shadow gets added to the right side when it should only get added to the slide that is currently moving.

Here's the jquery

```
// Add shadow to menu once link has been clicked
$('.back').click(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.sub-menu').addClass('menu-shadow');
    },10);
});
```

i think it should be something like this

```
$(this).next('.sub-menu').addClass('menu-shadow');
```

but it does not work.

and here's the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/R6wHG/22/
You'll notice if you go up one level it is fine, it when you go up 2 levels + there's a problem due to the fact that all the sub-menus have the same class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is the parent of the clicked button

```
$('.back').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $this.parent().addClass('menu-shadow');
        //or $this.closest('.sub-menu').addClass('menu-shadow');
    }, 10);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that took me ages and still couldn't figure it out.